# Printing out a 2-D list so that each list prints out on a new line for the output in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

*I'm a very new beginner to programming, so if there is anything I can improve on in my code let me know.

I want to make it so that the output prints out the lists in new lines every time, and I got it to that somehow :), but it also prints [None] like a bunch of times, could someone explain to me why it happens and how I would be able to get rid of it whether it is through the use of "\r" or something else.

This is my code:

```
# All Toppings
toppings = ["cheese", "olives", "pepperoni", "mushrooms", "sausage", "pineapple", "anchovies"]

# The Prices
prices = ["$2", "$6", "$1", "$3", "$2", "$7", "$2"]
prices.sort()

# Number of Toppings
num_pizzas = len(toppings)

# Combing Pizza Toppings and Prices
pizza_and_prices = list(map(list,zip(prices,toppings)))

#After the Guy Bought the Last Anchovies Slice
pizza_and_prices.pop()
pizza_and_prices.append(["$2.5", "peppers"])

#ACTUAL MENU
print("***TOOZIE'S PIZZARIA***")
print("We sell " + str(num_pizzas) + " different kinds of Pizza!")
print(list(map(print, pizza_and_prices)))
```

This is the output:

```
***TOOZIE'S PIZZARIA***
We sell 7 different kinds of Pizza!
['$1', 'cheese']
['$2', 'olives']
['$2', 'pepperoni']
['$2', 'mushrooms']
['$3', 'sausage']
['$6', 'pineapple']
['$2.5', 'peppers']
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/

the map function runs a given function depending on the number of objects in an iterable. In this case the iterable is a list containing the prices of our pizzas and the toppings of our pizzas. The problem is these objects are being stored as two seperate objects somewhere and when you're asking it to be mapped as a list, it finds more iterations than it needs to go on.

note how there's 7 nones printed, this is evidence that it's getting through the first seven items: 1, cheese, 2, olives, 2, pepperoni, and 2

and outputs those as it should, but then continues to output things for the remaining 7 items. mushrooms, 3, sausage, 6, pineapple, 2.5, peppers.

but it has nothing to output because there's nothing stored in those parts of the iterable, you've ran out of references.

that's what's happening. As for solving it however, I have to say I'm a bit stumped with the amount of variable type changeups happening. I'd recommend learning about dictionaries in Python because those are the best tools for having string variables sorted by indexable values, so you could have a price and topping matched into one object and not have to canoodle with the map() function as much

Comment: I haven't learned about dictionaries yet, but I'm pretty sure you are right that it would be better store all these different values. However, the list that I have is a 2-D list, so the the item at index 0 is another 'mini-list' ['$1", cheese] and I have 7 of these 'mini-lists' within the main list named pizza_and_prices so I'm not sure if what you said about it going through the first 7 items is true, because in the output it did end up outputting all of my 7 'mini-lists,' but after it did that, it ended up printing [None] 7x.

Comment: I could be wrong because I am just starting off, but if you could clarify that would be great. If you want, I could print pizza_and_prices to show you what it looks like, if you believe that would help.

Comment: I ran your code and it seemed to go okay, in that the pizza_and_prices list items printed as expected. I think what's happening here is that the map() function is going wiggy.
the map function iterates through an object, and because each individual object is a double list, I also think it's iterating through each list item. That's my best guess/reasoning as to why you're getting 14 outs instead of the planned 7.

Comment: as for what dictionaries are, they're like lists, but they're designed to store data using keys instead of having an index number per item or object. In short, it can sort items by a group of other key names.